# Change the background color of textbox when the text of this textbox is changed?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

There is a textbox in the control panel of a webpart.The user input the colorString into the textbox,and then move the curosr out of the textbox,so the background color of this textbox will be changed.But the vertical scroll bar should not be moved.What's the idea to handle it?

Here is my idea:
The AutoPostBack property of this textbox is set true,and I write a event to change background color when the text of this textbox is changed.Though the background color can be changed,the control panel is also refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even do this at client side using jQuery or JavaScript. However, you are dependent on user to enter the correct color text, else it won't work.